# Correlation between two image(binary image)

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, detection, correlation

I have two binary image like this. I have a data set with lots of picture like at the bottom but with differents signs.

[image]

and

[image]

I would like to compare them in order to know if it's the same figure or not (especially inside the triangle). I took a look in Sift and Surf feature but it's doesn't work well on this type of picture (it find matchning point whereas the two picture are different,especially inside).

I also hear about SVM but i don't know if i have to implement it for this type of problem.

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: if both images are aligned and of same size, you could use chamfer matching (in both directions)

Comment: http://hpics.li is classified as a site for `Phishing and Other Frauds`. I suggest you post your images elsewhere.

Comment: Ahh do you have another website ? Because i don't have enough reputation to upload my images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not use SURF features  on the binary image as you have already discarded a lot of information at that stage with your edge detector.

You could also use the [Linear](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) or [Circle Hough Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) that in this case could tell you a lot about image differences.

Answer (score 0):

If you wat to find 2 exactly identical images, simply use hash functions like md5.
But if you want to find related ( not exatcly identical) images, you are running in trouble ;). look for artificial neural network libs...

Comment: So you suggest me to have an neural network,that's it ?

Comment: only if you want detect related pictures, this is a very complex problem. whats about opencv? this jlib should solve yur problem

Comment: Using neaural network is difficult because i don't have a big data sef of training example...

Comment: ok, then try to calculate the cross corrolation. you can yuse opencv' cvMatchTemplate() method